# How to compare two rows of a table

Tags: sql

I have a sample table with input as shown. In actual it has large amounts of data. The input and output as shown:

```
    I/P-                                                 O/P-

|ID | Role | Status |                     |ID | Role | Status | Final |
|:-:|:----:|:------:|                     |:-:|:----:|:------:|:-----:|
| 1 | ABC  |  Pass  |                     | 1 | ABC  |  Pass  |   0   |
| 2 | PQR  |  Pass  |                     | 2 | PQR  |  Pass  |   0   |
| 1 | ABC  |  Fail  |                     | 1 | ABC  |  Fail  |   0   |
| 3 | PQR  |  Fail  |                     | 3 | PQR  |  Fail  |   0   |               
| 1 | XYZ  |  Fail  |                     | 1 | XYZ  |  Fail  |   1   |
| 3 | PQR  |  Fail  |                     | 3 | PQR  |  Fail  |   1   |
| 3 | XYZ  |  Pass  |                     | 3 | XYZ  |  Pass  |   0   | 
| 4 | XYZ  |  Fail  |                     | 4 | XYZ  |  Fail  |   1   |
```

So for a 'ID' (ex. ID=1) if Role is same for two or more records (ex. Role = 'ABC') then will status field. If for any of the selected record 'Status' = 'Pass' then will create a new field named Final with value 0 for all records(if for any of the record Status = 'Pass')
else will keep it 1(if there is no record with 'Status' = 'Pass'.

I know this we can do with Case statement while comparing columns. But not sure how to do with rows. Can someone please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Note that tables have _rows_ and _columns_, not records and fields.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do an exists check. And tis coud be written in different ways depending on your backend which you didn't specify:

```
select Id, Role, Status, 
  case when exists (select * from myTable t2 
                    where t1.Id = t2.Id
                    and t1.Role = t2.Role
                    and t2.Status = 'Pass') then 0 else 1 end as Final
from myTable t1;
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3c319eb523f7fda56e2961541e4bdd12)

PS: Either your sample output is wrong or your explanation. You may need to change the where part depending on your actual need.